# estimate for i-th  smooth  number,  gap  between consecutive  smooth  numbers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Does anyone know of the best estimates for $n_i$ and $n_{i+1}-n_i$ where $n_i$
is the $i-$th $y-$smooth number?

The best I could find was Tijdemann's estimate for the gap in terms of
$\frac{n_i}{(log(n_i))^c}$ where $c$ is a constant depending on y.

For $n_i$ itself one could "invert" $\Psi(n_i,y)$ the estimate for number of
smooth numbers, and get an estimate in terms if $i,$ but I wonder if it is
worked out or if there is a better way.

Comment: You might find useful to look at Granville's and Friedlander's paper MR1253496 (95b:11086)

Comment: Thank you! They do improve Tijdemann's result in the course of that paper, but using abc conjecture. They also mention a result by Stewart and Yu (unconditional) in the same direction.

Comment: The terminology "smooth" is admittedly entrenched in the (English) literature on this topic, but it's a poorly chosen term. The more modern term, which hopefully will oust the older term, is "friable".